# HTML Draw table with borders only for <tbody> and <tr>

Tags: html, border

I have an HTML table which looks like:

```
<table >
        <thead >
                <tr><th align="center" colspan="7" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">TEMP</th></tr>
                <tr><th align="right" colspan="7">In Lieu of XXXX(P)-28(L)</th></tr>
                <tr><th align="center" colspan="7">RECIEPT - HQ XYZ</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left" colspan="6">To    : 93 SDO</th>
                    <th align="left" colspan="5">Date : ________<?php ?></th>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left" colspan="6">From : 993 FPO</th>
                    <th align="left" colspan="5">Sheet No:________</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr><td  align="center" colspan="7" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">TEMP</td></tr>
            </tfoot>
        <tbody border="2" cellpadding="2" >
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>      
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>      
                <th>Points</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The CSS for the table is like this

```
<style>
    table { 
            page-break-inside:auto;
            border= 0px;
          }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; 
            page-break-after:auto 
            border=1px solid black;
          }
    thead { display:table-header-group;
            border=1px solid black;
          }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group;
            border= 0px;
          }
</style>
```

I am trying to achieve borders only for `<tbody>` and `<tr>` but it's not happening.
I have tried making `border` property for the table, `thead` and `foot` as `0px` and `collapsed`. But I am unable to achieve. Is it not possible to declare the border properties for individual tags such as tbody, tr, thead, tfoot etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `border : none;` instead of `border : 0px;`

Comment: The aim is to have NO Border for `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` but border WANTED ONLY for `<tbody>`. I ain't getting border unless border is declared for `<table>`.

Comment: @Raky I can't get what's your meaning. if you want border for `<tag>` just use `border : 1px solid #000` and if you don't want, use `border : none` . attention that you should use `:` in css not `=`

Comment: I want the bordering to start from <tbody> that is `<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>  
    <th>Points</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>  
    <th>Points</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
   </tr>'. Any other elements above this that is `<thead>` should have no border and again `<tfoor>` should Not have border. Only `<tbody>` should have border.

Comment: It seems the border property of all elements below of `<table>` are inherited. Which means unless `<table>` has a property set, you can't have it in sub-elements such as `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` and `<tfoot>`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS definition:

```
th {
     border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
```

(of course, later you adjust size and color)

BUT, all those `td`s after the first row of `tbody` must be converted do `th` to display the border around them.